# Transpose tensorflow minst model got huge difference in result

Tags: python, tensorflow

I wrote two version code for minst data set in tensorflow. The first one is just similar to the example code with input[None,784]
However, the second piece is what i change. I just modify the input scale to [784,None] and change some corresponding matrix format. 
I am confused with the difference in result. I am a beginner for tensorflow. Really wanna your help.

Thanks

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist.input_data as input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets(r"C:\Ruigy\NN\minst", one_hot=True)

def hidden_layer(X, sizeOutput, non_linear_name = ''):
    sizeInput = X.shape[1]
    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([sizeInput,sizeOutput]))
    B = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([sizeOutput]))
    Y = tf.matmul(X,W) + B
    if non_linear_name == '':             return   Y
    elif non_linear_name == 'softmax':    A = tf.nn.softmax(Y)
    elif non_linear_name == 'ReLU':       A = tf.nn.relu(Y)
    return A



X       = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784],name = 'Input')
Y_LABEL = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10], name = 'Label')
Y_linear= hidden_layer(X,Y_LABEL.shape[1])

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=Y_LABEL, 
logits=Y_linear))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

for _ in range(1000):
    batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={X: batch_xs, Y_LABEL: batch_ys})

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(Y_linear, 1), tf.argmax(Y_LABEL, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={X: mnist.test.images, Y_LABEL: mnist.test.labels}))
```

The result is 0.9188

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist.input_data as input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets(r"C:\Ruigy\NN\minst", one_hot=True)

def hidden_layer(X, sizeOutput, non_linear_name = ''):
    sizeInput = X.shape[0]
    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([sizeInput,sizeOutput]))
    B = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([sizeOutput,1]))
    Y = tf.matmul(W,X,True) + B
    if non_linear_name == '':             return   Y
    elif non_linear_name == 'softmax':    A = tf.nn.softmax(Y)
    elif non_linear_name == 'ReLU':       A = tf.nn.relu(Y)
    return A



X       = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [784,None],name = 'Input')
Y_LABEL = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [10,None], name = 'Label')
Y_linear= hidden_layer(X,Y_LABEL.shape[0])

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=Y_LABEL, 
logits=Y_linear))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

for _ in range(1000):
    batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={X: batch_xs.T, Y_LABEL: batch_ys.T})

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(Y_linear, 0), tf.argmax(Y_LABEL, 0))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={X: mnist.test.images.T, Y_LABEL: mnist.test.labels.T}))
```

The result is 0.6638

I am really confused. where am i wrong ? I just wanna change the format.

Answer (score 0):

Data is to be taken in the same format as given in the dataset. If you want to change format, take a tf.tranpose() for Input after assigning to the placeholder